# What are lions and tigers eating in Satyug?

Tags: puranas, food, yuga, animals

In Satyug the animals get along with each other and play together, no enemies, as says Skand Puran Chapter 17.

So lions and tigers, cheetah, jaguar, what are they eating ?

Cause in Kaliyug they hunt deer and eat them. Mountain lions break into farm in rural places and eat chickens and goats also, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> कृते त्वस्थि गताः प्राणास्त्रेतायां मांसमाश्रिताः
> द्वापरे रुधिरं चैव कलौ त्वन्नादिषु स्थिताः ३२ [-Paraashara Dharma Shastra 1.32](https://archive.org/details/ParasharaSmriti/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater)

> The Praana resides in  the bones in Krita, exists in the flesh in Treta, in the blood in Dvaapara and resides in food and external objects in the Kali.

So, presumably, those tigers didn't need to eat anything at all. Neither did humans. It makes sense once you consider how people did Tapasyaa for thousands of years, supposedly, continuously. Did they not eat and drink? Yep, they didn't because they didn't need to.

Comment: I see, thanks so much !

Comment: that doesn't make sense - without food the bones cannot grow to being with. what it probably means is that they can go much longer without eating - e.g. in kali once food is digested the body is unable to extract energy just from blood. in dwapara, once blood is low, body is unable to extract energy from flesh.. similarly treta-flesh, krita-bones.

Comment: Could you pleas do me (and others) a favor and either explain your words in a way english-only speakers can understand, or, even better link some translation/explanation  site? Not Praana nor Krita neither Treta gets sensible hits on wikipedia in this context.

Comment: @mar Praana is the force that motivates 'change'. If the Praana is in the bones, there's no need for 'change' (such as movement, respiration or thinking) to occur via food because the source of Praana is already in the body, without eating. Of course, growth of body would still require input of Bhu tattva, we know that in Krita, people had stomachs, so that served a use. 
As for your theory, where would the 'energy' in blood come from? from food, no? so how can Praana be situated in the blood or others? You're suggesting that the source is food in all Yugas, which I don't think is correct.

Comment: @GyroGearloose These are quite basic terms. Praana cannot really be translated without losing the majority of the meaning, so I haven't done so. As for Krita (aka Satya) and others, they're simply the names of the 4 Yugas, that I assume everyone knows about, at this point.

I recommend you look up 'Wisdom-library' for basic explanations of all these terms, thanks.

Comment: https://www.wisdomlib.org/ I will look there, thanks a lot.

Comment: @GyroGearloose for Praana, search it as just 'Prana', it will give you the result. I like to add the extra a for the purpose of preservation of pronunciation in absence of proper transliteration.

Comment: I looked at your mentioned link but can't get anything beside they want some money. Where I can get without, searching for Krita doesn't get me anywhere. And I doubt htat there would be better answer if I'd pay money.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150767/discussion-between-dushyant-shreyaskar-and-gyro-gearloose).

Comment: I will try to access the chat, but I have not done this often, so I might fail on trivial clicks missed ore misdone. Here I go.

Comment: @GyroGearloose - i'm saying it is not possible for bones to grow if they did not eat food from the moment they were born. so food is the initial source, and after the baby is fully grown into a man, then eat very little food is enough to sustain for a long time cos they can extract energy from bones. but even that is not infinite, they have to replenish with food at some point.